# Play sound continuosly until user stops

Tags: android, media-player

I'm developing a test app that when the automated testing process finishes an alarm sound is played to notify the operator.

This sound is a 3secs duration alarm ringtone, and I need to be played in loop until the user touches the phone screen.

This is the way I implement the mediaplayer:

```
mp = MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.this, R.raw.alarm);
    try {
        mp.prepare();
        mp.setLooping(true);
        } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        mp.start();
    }
```

I have defined the `mp.setLooping` that should make the sound play continuosly, but it doesn't.

Then, to stop the sound touching the screen:

```
@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent (MotionEvent event) {
    if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
        /*If sound is playing, stops*/
        if (mp.isPlaying()) {
            mp.stop();
        }
        return true;
    }
    return super.onTouchEvent(event);
}
```

So if `mp.setLooping` is not working, how should I make the sound play continuosly?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you instantiate a MediaPlayer with `create()`, it is returned in a prepared state and you must not call `prepare()` on it. In your case, this is throwing an Exception, and therefore `mp.setLooping(true)` isn't being called.

Comment: Works that way! Anyway, now I can't stop the alarm touching the screen, the sound keeps playing all the time. What is wrong with the onTouchEvent method?

Comment: Well, I have a main activity where I manage all the global methods and where this method is defined, but the UI consists on 3 fragments, and I use viewPager to navigate through them.

Comment: Ok Mike, could you edit your post with this method? Or is it the same structure as onTouchEvent?

Comment: Just changing `onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event)` for `dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent event)` force closes the app. About returning true, how should I code then not to happen that?

Comment: There is no error on logcat :S the app just force closes, that's all ¿?

Comment: Yeah `return super.dispatchTouchEvent(event);` but not working

Comment: I've deleted all logCat filters but still it is blank. It doesn't throw any error. My code consists on one MainActivity where I manage all global methods. Then I have 3 fragments, one for each app screen. The MainActivity doesn't have UI, it just implements the viewPager. Maybe should I call mediaplayer on each fragment and also implement onTouchEvent() on each fragment?

Comment: I don't know what to tell you. I just ran a test with an Activity, a ViewPager, Fragments, a MediaPlayer, and the `dispatchTouchEvent()` method overridden, and I got no errors. You might try cleaning and rebuilding the project, restarting the IDE, etc.

Comment: Mike, I'll appreciate that you could post an answer with this idea in the new thread I've created for this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25605803/stop-mediaplayer-when-touch-screen

Comment: It get's closed when I touch the screen

Comment: Ok, I'll try also using a try catch statemnt, maybe there is any exception that isn't being caught... don't know...

Comment: Mike, I've been able to see the in the logcat what is the error, but I don't know how to solve. I'm leaving home now, tomorrow will update the post with the LogCat

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/60414/discussion-on-answer-by-mike-m-play-sound-continuosly-until-user-stops).

Comment: Mike, I've updated a new question with the logCat info, please have a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25605803/stop-mediaplayer-when-touch-screen

Answer (score -1):

```
mp = MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.this, R.raw.alarm);
mp.start();
mp.setLooping(true);
```